# replace whitespace and new line with comma

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like this:

> filenames = 'file_1, file2,  file3\nfile4'

I want to replace whitespaces with no space and new line with comma

So far i have tried this:

```
file_name = re.sub(r"\s+", "", filenames, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

which is returning :

> file_name = 'file_1,file2,file3file4'

but i want :

```
filenames = 'file1,file2,file3,file4'
```

Comment: `\s` also matches a newline.  First replace the newlines with a comma, then replace the spaces with a comma and replace the underscore with an empty string.

Comment: Should `'file 1, foo, bar'` be replaced by `'file1,foo,bar'` ? (note the space between `file` and `1`)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
file_name = re.sub(r"[,\s]+", ",", filenames, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference from your written requirements and your desired output.

Firstly you need to replace '\n' with ', ' so it looks like your desired output.

Secondly, you are saying you want whitespaces with no spaces but in your desired output there is still spaces.

This is a fix for '\n':

```
doc = 'file_1, file2, file3\nfile4'
doc = doc.replace('\n', ', ')
print(doc)
file_1, file2, file3, file4
```

If you want whitespaces with no spaces:

```
doc = doc.replace(' ', '')
print(doc)
file_1,file2,file3,file4
```

Answer (score 1):

A non regex solution would be to split, trim and join, after replacing all `\n` by `','`. This will prevent removing needed spaces (in example, if a filename contains a space)

```
filenames = 'file_1, file2, file3\nfile4, file         5'
','.join(filter(None, [s.strip() for s in filenames.replace('\n', ',').split(',')]))
# 'file_1,file2,file3,file4,file         5'
```

`filter(None, [...])` will remove any empty string, if, in example, you have `'foo,bar,,hello\n\nworld'`